# Why can't I successfully install mysql server?

Tags: linux, mysql, unix, database, installation

It's very easy. All I want to do is this:

```
aptitude remove mysql-server mysql-server-5.0 --purge
aptitude install mysql-server
```

But when I try to run that I get this error:

```
 root@db2:/etc# aptitude install mysql-server
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree
    Reading state information... Done
    Reading extended state information
    Initializing package states... Done
    The following NEW packages will be installed:
      libhtml-template-perl{a} mysql-server mysql-server-5.0{a} mysql-server-core-5.0{a}
    0 packages upgraded, 4 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
    Need to get 0B/27.7MB of archives. After unpacking 91.1MB will be used.
    Do you want to continue? [Y/n/?] y
    Writing extended state information... Done
    Preconfiguring packages ...
    Selecting previously deselected package mysql-server-core-5.0.
    (Reading database ... 17213 files and directories currently installed.)
    Unpacking mysql-server-core-5.0 (from .../mysql-server-core-5.0_5.1.30really5.0.75-0ubuntu10.2_amd64.deb) ...
    Selecting previously deselected package mysql-server-5.0.
    Unpacking mysql-server-5.0 (from .../mysql-server-5.0_5.1.30really5.0.75-0ubuntu10.2_amd64.deb) ...
     * Stopping MySQL database server mysqld                                                                                              [ OK ]
    Selecting previously deselected package libhtml-template-perl.
    Unpacking libhtml-template-perl (from .../libhtml-template-perl_2.9-1_all.deb) ...
    Selecting previously deselected package mysql-server.
    Unpacking mysql-server (from .../mysql-server_5.1.30really5.0.75-0ubuntu10.2_all.deb) ...
     * Stopping MySQL database server mysqld                                                                                              [ OK ]
    Setting up mysql-server-core-5.0 (5.1.30really5.0.75-0ubuntu10.2) ...
    Setting up mysql-server-5.0 (5.1.30really5.0.75-0ubuntu10.2) ...
     * Stopping MySQL database server mysqld                                                                                              [ OK ]
    /var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-server-5.0.postinst: line 144: /etc/mysql/conf.d/old_passwords.cnf: No such file or directory
    dpkg: error processing mysql-server-5.0 (--configure):
     subprocess post-installation script returned error exit status 1
    Setting up libhtml-template-perl (2.9-1) ...
    dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
     mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.0; however:
      Package mysql-server-5.0 is not configured yet.
    dpkg: error processing mysql-server (--configure):
     dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
    No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                              Errors were encountered while proce                        ssing:
     mysql-server-5.0
     mysql-server
    E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
    A package failed to install.  Trying to recover:
    Setting up mysql-server-5.0 (5.1.30really5.0.75-0ubuntu10.2) ...
     * Stopping MySQL database server mysqld                                                                                              [ OK ]
    /var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-server-5.0.postinst: line 144: /etc/mysql/conf.d/old_passwords.cnf: No such file or directory
    dpkg: error processing mysql-server-5.0 (--configure):
     subprocess post-installation script returned error exit status 1
    dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
     mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.0; however:
      Package mysql-server-5.0 is not configured yet.
    dpkg: error processing mysql-server (--configure):
     dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
    Errors were encountered while processing:
     mysql-server-5.0
     mysql-server
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree
    Reading state information... Done
    Reading extended state information
    Initializing package states... Done
    Writing extended state information... Done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

aptitude has sometimes problems with dependencies, have you tried?

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install mysql-server [.........]
sudo apt-get remove mysql-server [........]
```